# Start an eventhandler when my timer value reaches 0

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, event-handling, navigation

This is my code for a timer, I want to load my gameover.xaml once my timer reaches 0. How do I connect the event.

```
    public void StartTimer(object o, RoutedEventArgs sender)
    {
        myDispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 1000 Milliseconds 
        myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
        myDispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    // counter
    int i = 60;


    public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {
       timerBlock.Text = "Time: " + i--.ToString() + "s";
    }
```

And here is my event method

```
    private void gameOverEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/gameOver.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

how can I do this -

```
if (i <= 0)
    something += new EventHandler(gameOverEvent);
```

What shall I put in something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to have a gameOverEvent at all, you could just check if i = 0 in the Each_Tick event handler, and navigate to the game over page if it is

```
public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender) 
{ 
   timerBlock.Text = "Time: " + i--.ToString() + "s";

   if(i = 0)
   {
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/gameOver.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i <= 0)
    gameOverEvent(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement an Eventhandler in your class like

```
public event EventHandler GameLost;
```

From this class you can raise the event

```
if ((this.GameLost != null) && (i <= 0))
    this.GameLost(this, new EventArgs());
```

See this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers) for a more detailed guide.